# Proving $\lim _{x \to \infty} \frac {\log x} x \int_2^x \frac 1 {\log t} \, \mathrm d t = 1 $

Tags: integration, limits, definite-integrals

I am trying to prove $$\lim _{x \to \infty} \frac {\log x} x \int_2^x \frac 1 {\log t} \, \mathrm d t = 1 $$

Any hints? I have bounded the integral below easily but I am having trouble finding a suitable upper bound.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: Use the fundamental theorem of calculus and L'Hospital rule.

Comment: Ah thanks, I should have seen that, but was trying to do it directly by bounding the integral

Answer (score 4):

Sorry, I first did not read that you only wanted a hint.

I suggest to use L'Hospital rule,

> $$\lim_{x\to+\infty}\frac{\int_2^x\frac{1}{\log t}\,dt}{x/\log x}=\lim_{x\to+\infty}\frac{1/\log x}{D(x/\log x)}=\lim_{x\to+\infty}\frac{\log x}{\log x-1}=1.$$

Comment: I have a doubt how to ensure the form so that you can apply the L'Hospital rule on it.

Comment: @Rajada Could you be more precise? With what of the conditions do you have a problem?

Comment: Means you have to ensure that the form on which you are applying L'Hospital rule must be $\frac{\infty}{\infty}$ or $\frac{0}{0}$. So, I want to know how are you checking that? I am a bit confused about the integration part. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Since $1/\log t>1/t$ for $t>2$, we find, by comparison, that the integral $\int_2^x1/\log t\,dt\to+\infty$ as $x\to+\infty$, since $\int_2^x1/t\,dt\to+\infty$ as $x\to+\infty$.

Answer (score 1):

Without using the L'Hospital rule, you can integrate by parts $$\int_{2}^{x}\frac{dt}{\log\left(t\right)}=\frac{x}{\log\left(x\right)}-\frac{2}{\log\left(2\right)}+\int_{2}^{x}\frac{dt}{\log^{2}\left(t\right)}=\frac{x}{\log\left(x\right)}+O\left(\frac{x}{\log^{2}\left(x\right)}\right)$$ hence $$\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}\frac{\log\left(x\right)}{x}\int_{2}^{x}\frac{dt}{\log\left(t\right)}=1.$$